# Goodman gas furnace won't light

Tags: furnace

I am trying to resurrect a Goodman gas furnace that hasn't run in a few years. I have gas to the unit, but no ignition. Vent blower starts up initially, but soon goes to intermittent operation, I assume because the burners don't light. It may just need to have the lines in the furnace bled, but I'm leery to do that since it sits right next to another furnace that is functional. I'm having a hard time checking operation when the thermostat is turned on because the thermostat is upstairs while the furnace is down. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the model number?  Can you give us a detailed step-by-step of the current ignition sequence?  While you're initially setting the unit up, simply bypass the thermostat. Shorting `R` to `W` simulates a call for heat.

Comment: Not lighting can be lots of different problems bad thermocouple, debris on burners that need cleaning spider webs on the air intake affecting the air/gas mixture lots of things more information is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I downloaded a Goodman manual and used it to check all the switches. All checked good. Finally figured out how to check startup conditions and found 14V output from the board to the gas valve with 27V from the transformer. Currently hunting for a new board locally (near Knoxville, TN.)